# Date conversion in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

How to convert `yyyy-dd-mm (Ex : 2016-31-10) to dd-MMM-yy(Ex: 31-OCT-16)` using spark sql? 
I have tried this way but it's not working

```
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE, "yyyy-MM-dd"), "dd-MMM-yy") AS STRING) AS DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
date_format(to_date(date, 'yyyy-dd-mm'), 'dd-MMM-yy') as date
```